# Difference between HttpResponse: SetCookie, AppendCookie, Cookies.Add

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

there are some different ways to create multi value cookies in ASP.NET:

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
cookie["Information 1"] = "value 1";
cookie["Information 2"] = "value 2";

// first way
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

// second way
Response.AppendCookie(cookie);

// third way
Response.SetCookie(cookie);
```

When should I use which way? I've read that `SetCookie` method updates the cookie, if it already exits. Doesn't the other ways update the existing cookie as well?

And is the following code best practice for writing single value cookies?

`Response.Cookies["MyCookie"].Value = "value";`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> When should I use which way?

It's depends on what Cookie operation you want to do.

Note that `Add` and `AppendCookie` are doing the same functionality except the fact that with `AppendCookie` you're not referencing the `Cookies` property of the `Response` `class` and it's doing it for you.

- `Response.Cookies.Add` - **Adds** the specified cookie to the cookie
  collection.
- `Response.AppendCookie` - **Adds** an HTTP cookie to the
  **intrinsic** cookie collection
- `Response.SetCookie` - **Updates** an existing cookie in the cookie
  collection.

`Exceptions` will not be thrown when duplicates cookies are added or when attempting to update not-exist cookie.

The main `exception` of these methods is: `HttpException` (*A cookie is appended after the HTTP headers have been sent.*)

The Add method allows duplicate cookies in the cookie collection. Use the Set method to ensure the uniqueness of cookies in the cookie collection.

Thanks for [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/)!

Comment: `SetCookie` updates the existing cookie: does this mean that if the cookie is not existing there will be an exception or the cookie will not be set? And doesn't the other methods updates the cookie if there is already a cookie with the same name?

Comment: Okay, thanks for explaining.. but then I don't understand when to use any other method as `Response.SetCookie` - because thats the safest way for writing unique cookies.

Comment: @FelixC As I said, you can use the `Set` method to ensure the uniqueness of cookies in the cookie collection.

Comment: Was having all sorts of trouble with this, until I read your comment about cookie appending after headers.  Got it working using `SetCookie` *before* setting the context response.

Answer (score 31):

If I remember correctly both

```
Response.Cookies.Add(..)
```

and

```
Response.AppendCookie(..)
```

will allow multiple cookies of the same name to be appended to the response.

On the other hand

```
Response.SetCookie(..)
```

and

```
Response.Cookies[key].Value = value;
```

will always overwrite previous cookies of the same name.

Comment: Also worth pointing out is the following message on the reference documentation (MSDN) for both [`AppendCookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.appendcookie) and [`SetCookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.setcookie): *"This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."*

Comment: The alternative then is to use `System.Web.HttpCookieCollection.Set(HttpCookie cookie)` and `System.Web.HttpCookieCollection.Add(HttpCookie cookie)` e.g. `Response.Cookies.Set(new HttpCookie("cookieName"))`.

Answer (score 7):

To piggyback on [tne's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2266481/tne) comment in Wiktor's reply, `AppendCookie` and `SetCookie` shouldn't be used - they're for internal use by the .NET framework. They shouldn't be public but they are, my guess would be as a hack for the IIS pipeline somewhere else.

So you should do your cookie setting this way (or write an extension method for setting multiple cookies):

```
string cookieName = "SomeCookie";
string cookieValue = "2017";

if (Response.Cookies[cookieName] == null)
{
    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(cookieName, cookieValue));
}
else
{
    Response.Cookies[cookieName].Value = cookieValue;
}
```